# SPSS Data Management

Tags: anova, spss, multivariate-analysis, dataset

I am not an expert of SPSS and I would like to ask a question related to data management.

I need to identify the respondents that answered yes I used it to all of the following question:

I used a car, 
I used a bike,
I used a van, 
I used a scouter.

My aim is to identify people that used all of the above options.

Can someone help me in identifying the right process to execute?

Many thanks

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. I don't think this question is clear enough to be suitable for migration to Stack Overflow. You may be interested in the key words "filter" and "crosstabs".

Comment: Thanks for your useful support. But, I am afraid that it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the best way to approach this is to read the base users guide that would have come with SPSS.  However, I would suggest using four separate fields that can be subsequently analysed independently or in combination.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already computed the variables. My problem is to create a crosstabs where it shows the percentage of people that contemporarily used: CAR, VAN, Bike and scouter. PS: I would not have asked any question If had found my answer in the base users guide.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I have only just found the messages area.  If your separate variables were coded as 0 and 1 for no and yes respectively, then you could add them to produce another variable, where an answer of 4 would give you what you wanted,  Another way could be with a compound IF statement.